# button animation/function to toggle views in xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, button

I'm fairly new to xcode/swift and am implementing a humburger menu animation (burger to X) that toggles between two views. I have achieved the task of getting to the SettingVC when you press the menu button via a push segue but I can't figure out how to get back to the main view when the X is tapped. This is the function I'm currently using.

```
@IBAction func onMenu(sender: DOHamburgerButton) {

    if sender.selected {
        sender.deselect()

    } else {
        sender.select()
        performSegueWithIdentifier("gotoSettingVC", sender: self)
    }

}
```

Comment: Try `self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)` (if `gotoSettingVC` is a show segue) or `self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)` (if `gotoSettingVC` is a modal segue).

Comment: where in the function do I put that? and what if it's a push segue?

Comment: After `sender.deselect()`, and push and show are the same I think.

Comment: tried both with no luck :(

Comment: You can use this to go back to the root VC   self.view.window!.rootViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)

Comment: tried this with no luck either: self.navigationController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: { () -> Void in })

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you present another view controller. If you push a view controller onto a navigation stack, you can call one of the popViewController functions on the navigation controller.

If it is presented modally, you can call the dismiss function on the presented view controller.